# Why does my Spring controller not handle an OPTIONS request sent by GraphiQL?

Tags: java, spring, xss, graphql, graphql-java

I'm trying to make the [GraphQL Java server](https://github.com/graphql-java/todomvc-relay-java) work with GraphiQL server.

Using the GraphiQL running locally I submit a query with the following parameters:

[image: GraphiQL query and its results]

My Spring controller (copied from [here](https://github.com/graphql-java/todomvc-relay-java/blob/master/src/main/java/todomvc/GraphQLController.java)) looks like this:

```
@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MavenController {
    private final MavenSchema schema = new MavenSchema();
    private final GraphQL graphql = new GraphQL(schema.getSchema());
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MavenController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/graphql", method = RequestMethod.OPTIONS, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public Object executeOperation(@RequestBody Map body) {
        log.error("body: " + body);
        final String query = (String) body.get("query");
        final Map<String, Object> variables = (Map<String, Object>) body.get("variables");
        final ExecutionResult executionResult = graphql.execute(query, (Object) null, variables);
        final Map<String, Object> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        if (executionResult.getErrors().size() > 0) {
            result.put("errors", executionResult.getErrors());
            log.error("Errors: {}", executionResult.getErrors());
        }
        log.error("data: " + executionResult.getData());
        result.put("data", executionResult.getData());
        return result;
    }
}
```

In theory, `executeOperation` should be invoked, when I submit the query in GraphiQL. It's not, I don't see the log statement in the console output.

What am I doing wron? How can I make sure that the `MavenController.executeOperation` is called, when a query is submitted in GraphiQL?

**Update 1 (13.01.2017 13:35 MSK):** Here is a tutorial on how to reproduce the error. My goal is to create a Java-based GraphQL server, with which I can interact using GraphiQL. If possible, this should work locally.

I’ve [read](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/issues/223) that in order to do that, following steps are necessary:

> 1. Set up a GraphQL server. An example of this can be found here https://github.com/graphql-java/todomvc-relay-java. That example uses Spring Boot, but you can use whatever HTTP server you like to get that going.
> 2. Set up the GraphiQL server. That is a bit beyond the scope of this project, but basically you need to get GraphiQL talking to the server in step 1 above. It will use introspection to load the schema.

I checked out the project [todomvc-relay-java](https://github.com/graphql-java/todomvc-relay-java), modified it according to my needs and put it into directory `E:\graphiql-java\graphql-server`. You can download an archive with that directory [here](http://www.altruix.cc/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/graphql-server.zip).

**Step 1: Install Node.JS**

**Step 2**

Go to `E:\graphiql-java\graphql-server\app` and run `npm install` there.

**Step 3**

Run `npm start` from the same directory.

**Step 4**

Go to `E:\graphiql-java\graphql-server` and run `gradlew start` there.

**Step 5**

Run `docker run -p 8888:8080 -d -e GRAPHQL_SERVER=http://localhost:8080/graphql merapar/graphql-browser-docker`.

Docker sources: [graphql-browser-docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/merapar/graphql-browser-docker/)

**Step 6**

Launch Chrome with disabled XSS check, e. g. `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"  --args --disable-xss-auditor`. Some sources claim you have to kill all other Chrome instances in order for these arguments to have any effect.

**Step 7**

Open http://localhost:8888/ in that browser.

**Step 8**

Try to run query

`{
  allArtifacts(group: "com.graphql-java", name: "graphql-java") {
    group
    name
    version
  }
}`

Actual results:

1) Error in the **Console** tab of Chrome: `Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:8080/graphql. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8888' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`.

[image: Errors in the "Console" tab]

2) Errors in the **Network** tab of Chrome:

[image: Errors in the "Network" tab]

**Update 2 (14.01.2017 13:51):** Currently, CORS is configured in the Java appliction in the following way.

Main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry
                        .addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedMethods("OPTIONS")
                        .allowedOrigins("*")
                        .allowedHeaders(
                                "Access-Control-Request-Headers",
                                "Access-Control-Request-Method",
                                "Host",
                                "Connection",
                                "Origin",
                                "User-Agent",
                                "Accept",
                                "Referer",
                                "Accept-Encoding",
                                "Accept-Language",
                                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
                        )
                        .allowCredentials(true)
                        ;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` subclass:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringWebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("SpringWebSecurityConfiguration");
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        http
                .addFilterBefore(new CorsFilter(source), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
                .httpBasic()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                    .disable();
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

The controller:

```
@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MavenController {
    private final MavenSchema schema = new MavenSchema();
    private final GraphQL graphql = new GraphQL(schema.getSchema());
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MavenController.class);

    @CrossOrigin(
            origins = {"http://localhost:8888", "*"},
            methods = {RequestMethod.OPTIONS},
            allowedHeaders = {"Access-Control-Request-Headers",
            "Access-Control-Request-Method",
            "Host",
            "Connection",
            "Origin",
            "User-Agent",
            "Accept",
            "Referer",
            "Accept-Encoding",
            "Accept-Language",
             "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"},
            exposedHeaders = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
             )
    @RequestMapping(value = "/graphql", method = RequestMethod.OPTIONS, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public Object executeOperation(@RequestBody Map body) {
        [...]
    }
}
```

`MavenController.executeOperation` is the method that's supposed to be called, when I issue a query request in GraphiQL.

**Update 3 (15.01.2017 22:05):** Tried to use `CORSFilter`, new source code is [here](http://www.altruix.cc/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/2016_01_15_main.zip). No result, I'm still getting "Invalid CORS response" error.

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Comment: @AlanHay See my update 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the with the usage of `.allowedMethods("OPTIONS")`configuration in your application.

Pre-flight requests by design sent with `OPTIONS` request method.

Access-Control-Request-Method is added by the browser automatically and `allowedMethods` property actually controls what request method are allowed for the actual request.

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests),

> The Access-Control-Request-Method header notifies the server as part
>   of a preflight request that when the actual request is sent, it will
>   be sent with a POST request method.

So it is `POST` method and and the request fails as you're only allowing `OPTIONS` when the validation is done.

So changing `allowedMethods` to `*` will match browser set `POST` request method for actual request.

After you do above change you'll get 405 as your controller only allows `OPTIONS` for your `POST` request.

So, you'll need to update the controller request mapping to allow POST for the actual request to succeed after pre-flight request.

Sample Response:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1484606833696,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "graphql.AssertException",
    "message": "arguments can't be null",
    "path": "/graphql"
}
```

I'm not sure looks like you've CORS configuration set at too many places. I just have to change the `.allowedMethods` in the spring security configuration to make it work the way I described. So you may want to look into that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure the Spring dispatcher servlet (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html) to handle OPTIONS.

Via XML you should do:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>yourSpringSvltname</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>dispatchOptionsRequest</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

Via Java Config:

```
 public class MyWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
      XmlWebApplicationContext appContext = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
      appContext.setConfigLocation("/WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-config.xml");

      ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher =
        container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
dispatchersetDispatchOptionsRequest(true);
      dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
      dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }

 }
```

Comment: I don't know if this answer works but it's correct in that you need to enable/configure CORS in Spring. CORS is a standard implemented  by web browsers to help prevent XSS attacks. It requires a server to specify that it accepts requests from certain front end URLs, so that requests can't just come from anywhere on the web. In a browser that implements CORS, I can't just have a piece of JavaScript on example.com call to bankofamerica.com because BoA only wants to handle requests from its front ends, not example.com. You can still make the request manually, but not on behalf of clueless users

Comment: @DmitryMinkovsky Thanks. I already configure CORS in my Java application. You can see the current configuration in my update 2.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue some time ago and I resolved it by creating of my own cors fiter bean.

Example:

```
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "accept, access-control-allow-origin, authorization, content-type");

    if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}

@Override
public void destroy() {

}
```

}

And I defined it in my configuration class:

```
@Bean(name = "corsFilter")
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public CORSFilter corsFilter() {
    return new CORSFilter();
}
```

And finally defined it on my servlet startup config:

```
servletContext.addFilter("corsFilter", new DelegatingFilterProxy("corsFilter")).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
```

P.S. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, but it didn't help. You can find a link to the archive with the new source code (with the `CORSFilter`) in my update 3.

Comment: Its really strange. Seems you have not valid config for your app. Because filter should works and handle request first.